# Webpack seems to be including node_modules of node_modules into bundle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, dependencies

So I have recently discovered that webpack seems to be including `node_modules` dependencies inside my top level `node_modules` dir into my actual bundle. For example, one dependency, `example-dep` depends on lodash, and so has a `node_modules` dir inside `node_modules/example-dep`, with lodash inside. Because `example-dep` imports *one* method from lodash, for some reason the entire lodash library is getting thrown into my bundle.

How can I fix this? Why are there nested `node_module` dirs inside my dependencies anyways? It's not like I am building those projects and trying to contribute to them, I literally just do `npm install example-dir`.

Answer (score 0):

Those `node_modules` directories are installed because are listed as `devDependencies` of the package (in case you want to build yourself or test). To install solely the built file

```
npm install --production <package>
```

or better

```
npm install --only=prod
```

For more details check https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.

Comment: Is there any way to set that flag in `package.json` without having to use a CLI argument or set NODE_ENV?

Comment: I don't think so. But you have to run that command every time you install a package so it makes sense.